# Modify custom HTML-Attribute with jquery does not affect CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an Element with the custom attribute `data-badge="1"` that looks like this:

```
<div id="badge" data-badge="1">
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Now I have some css styling the `:after` element of this divs chils-span. But as soon as the attribute `data-badge` is zero, I want to hide the `:after` element. So naturally I added this to the CSS

```
#badge span:after {
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    ...
}

#badge[data-badge="0"] span:after {
   display: none;
}
```

This works quite well if I load the page, but as soon as I change the "data-badge" attribute using jquery, the element will no longer be hidden. What can cause this?

Thank you for your help

EDIT:
Due to a request, here is the Jquery-Code aswell:

```
$(".button").click(function(){
   $("#badge").data("data-badge","0");
});
```

(Of course there is way more jquery-code but this is literally the only part, that has anything to do with this attribute. And the problem occurs also, if the data-badge attribute is changed via jquery in the browser-console)

Comment: Can you show us your JS/ jQuery code?

Comment: Unless you manually change the attribute, it is possible that jQuery does not actually change that value shown.

Comment: When you invoke `$(...).data('badge', '0')`, jQuery modified the `dataset` of the element, not the attribute you're willing to change. You'll have to use `$(...).attr('data-badge', '0')` instead

Comment: How are you changing the attribute? Please include the relevant js  code...It's different if you're doing it with `prop`, `attr`, `data`, ...

Comment: @Juggernaut, It does work in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/698903/. Did you make sure your `click` callback actually runs?

Comment: delete unnecesary  '.'  inside your selector before button =)

Comment: Note that if you're using jQuery v2 or earlier, the data is actually tracked completely independently of `dataset` as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to work fine as is;

```js
$(".button").click(function(){
   $("#badge").attr("data-badge","0");
});
```

```css
#badge span:after {
    display: block;
    content: "text";
}
#badge[data-badge="0"] span:after {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="badge" data-badge="1">
  <span></span>
</div>
<button class="button">click me</button>
```

There must be something else interfering

---

**Edit**
As commented, it seems the issue was the difference between `.data()` and `.attr()` in jQuery. To summarize:

1. [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) will read the value from data-* attributes, but writing will only update internally (will not apply to the the DOM)
2. [`.attr("data-*")`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) will both read and write directly to the DOM attribute, which will affect what css can be applied to it

Comment: I was using $("#badge").data, instead of "attr", as @haim770 pointed out. Thank you for your help

Comment: You summarized it well and it's useful for future readers just as mine